# Windows 10: symlink to an offline folder

Tags: windows-10, sync, symbolic-link, offline-files

I'm trying to streamline synchronisation of a game's save files between two networked Windows 10 machines. I wanted to try doing it locally without involving cloud services (which I will have to resort to if this turns out to be impossible).

I've shared the savegame folder in question and made it into a synchronised offline folder on the other machine. It's now accessible "offline", and can be found in the "Folder for offline files" when the network share isn't available.

This is where I'm stuck. I was then going to make a symlink to the synchronised offline folder at the proper location so that the game could find the files, but I can't figure out what path the offline folder has:

- It doesn't have any Properties in its context menu
- The path in explorer's address bar is unusually colloquial, starting with "Folder for offline files..." which isn't really a valid path as far as `cmd` is concerned
- I cannot drag and drop the folder into `cmd` to get the path

How do I symlink to an offline folder? Am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I was on the right track and that I had mistakenly symlinked the network path with a single leading `\` instead of `\\` because of ambiguity regarding the `mklink` command. Symlinking the non-reachable network path seems to work as expected.